# how get column index and row index in gridpane of javafx

Tags: java, javafx-2, javafx, javafx-8

how get column index and row index in `GridPane` of JavaFX. see the code below

```java
Text text1 = new Text("Text 1");
Text text2 = new Text("Text 2");
StackPane root = new StackPane();
GridPane gridPane = new GridPane();
gridPane.add(text1, 0, 0);
gridPane.add(text2, 1, 0);
```

When Mouse Entered On text1 I want to get the column index and row index of GridPane

```java
text1.setOnMouseEntered(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(MouseEvent e) {
        //want to get column index =0 and row index=0
    }
});
```

Please let me know.

Answer (score 10):

You can get the row index and column index by utilising the static methods `getRowIndex()` and `getColumnIndex()` which are located in the `GridPane` class.

```
System.out.println("Row: " + GridPane.getRowIndex(text1));
System.out.println("Column: " + GridPane.getColumnIndex(text1));
```

See for the [reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/layout/GridPane.html#getRowIndex(javafx.scene.Node)).

Comment: can i get index without getting add any node on grid pane

Comment: The method `GridPane.getColumnIndex(text1)` or `GridPane.getRowIndex(text1)` will not add any node on the GridPane. It just returns the index of the passed item.

Answer (score -1):

When i was looking for the same answer as OP I searched a lot and eventually found this.

```
GridPane.getColumnIndex((Node) e.getTarget());

GridPane.getRowIndex((Node) e.getTarget());
```

It works to get the index in an Integer format by clicking on the Node you want the coordinates from if you are using a GridPane to make your "Grid"

Comment: How is your answer any more useful than that of @ShreyasDave?