# How to add listener to cell in Gridview in javafx

Tags: javafx, controlsfx

there are no selectionModel in gridview in controlsFX, how can I do the same thing as selectionModel does?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17083974/how-get-column-index-and-row-index-in-gridpane-of-javafx

Comment: Related: [How to implement selection of Nodes in JavaFX](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40917005/how-to-implement-selection-of-nodes-in-javafx).